# iPhone XS Random Hard Reset

Tags: iphone

I have an iPhone XS (on Verizon) that randomly does a hard reset. Sometimes a few days, sometime in hours. When it restarts it is like a brand new phone, starting the setup prompts again. Apple replaced the iPhone XS a few days ago and it is still resetting. Verizon has replaced the SIM and is still resetting. Verizon has said the IMEI is missing from the profile but fixed it and it is still resetting. Have used two different Apple IDs while re-setting up the iPhone.

Have done restores from iCloud, Verizon and SanDisk.

Any suggestions?

Comment: when you say Apple replaced hardware, you mean they gave you new phone ?

Comment: yes . new iPhone XS.

Comment: so it is probably not hardware, but possibly software, what 3d party software do you install ?

Comment: Take the phone back!

Answer (score 1):

Replaced hardware (iPhone) has the same problem as the previous one.

That's is rare or improbable.

The chance are it is some malfunctioning app, that cripples the IOS.

Do not use restore (for now), use fresh install (clean install) to test for few days.

If nothing worked, take it back to the store.

Comment: trying "SETUP AS NEW" and not restoring from iCloud. No strange or unpopular apps. Thanks.

Comment: good luck, let me know if it worked

Comment: Hasn't worked. iPhone keeps doing a factory reset. Only seems to happen while it is being used. Will be fine for 3 to 5 days and then another random factory reset.